# Renaming Google Drive files via Google Sheet Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, rename, drive

I need to rename Google Drive files (inside a folder) by changing only name and replacing by names stored in a google sheet cell.
Expecting there are 24 files and 24 lines in my Sheet first files will get the first cell name....

thank you in advance

I found a script but wasn't able to make it works (didn't know if i have to add it in my Google sheet files via App Scripts or in my Drive file.

Comment: Please provide image of your sheet and explain how files in a folder correlate to names in a cell.  Your question sounds like you are talking to yourself but unfortunately none of us know what is already inside your head.  So please more details would help and images are useful too.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can clarify/explain your question thoroughly. As @Cooper said, please provide sample sheets and screenshots so we can understand your concern better.